# Return Single Tweets Twitter4J

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm playing around with Twitter4J and i'm curious as to how i can return a single tweet (most recent tweet). My code is below... But it's not working. The documentation on the libraries website isn't great, but i've tried my best to follow it. But any input would be great.

It should also be noted that i'm trying to not use a loop of any description (will use loops in future projects)

```
Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
Query query = new Query("source:twitter4j LFC");
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());
```

Comment: when you say "Not working", is it not returning anything or is it returning a tweet but that tweet isn't the latest one (or the one you are looking for). Please add more details as to what is wrong with the response.

Comment: Sorry, it's not returning anything at all. It compiled, but nothing was printed. Does the code look right to you? @LionsDen

Comment: you did not assign the value from result to status variable. I am surprised if this is even compiling. Please try the code that i have provided as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any relation between `result` and `status` variables, that's the reason it is not printing anything to you.

Try this,

```
 Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton(); 
 Query query = new Query("source:twitter4j LFC"); 
 QueryResult result = twitter.search(query); 
 for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
    System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText()); 
    break; // You can delete the 'break' in future when you decide to implement/enhance the logic as you have stated
 }
```

reference:
http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html (look at #4 Search for Tweets)